# Open neighborhood in the product topology

Tags: general-topology

*Let $\mathbb{R}^w=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{R}$. Then $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1,1)$ is open in box topology, but not in the product topology. The point $(0)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ has no basic open neighborhood $\subset \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1,1)$.*

It is written in one online lecture.

**Question 1**: Why this set is not open in product topology? Is it related to the fact the the open set in product topology must have a form like $U_1×U_2×U_3×...×U_n×R_{n+1}×R_{n+2}×...$ where $U_i$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$? Is this the complete answer?

**Question 2**: Why is there written the third sentence about the point $(0)_{i=1}^{\infty}$? Is it some argument to prove that this set is not open in product topology? Or it is additional unrelated information?

**Question 3**: Why point $(0)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ does not have a neighbourhood in this set? Can I give the same answer as in the first question?

**Question 4 (unrelated question)**: Can someone explain in very easy and descriptive manner why we call product topology the pointwise topology? I know about subbases of product topology. But can not grasp the idea how we move from this to the concept of pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence about $(0)_{i=1}^\infty$ is the justification (short) of the fact that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (-1,1)$ is not open in the product topology.

If the set $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (-1,1)$ were open in the product topology , we first not that the point $(0)_{i=1}^\infty$ is in it. So by the definition of the product topology there must be a basic subset of the form $U_1 \times U_2 \times \ldots \times U_n \times R_{n+1} \times R_{n+2} \times \ldots$ such that $$(0)_{i=1}^\infty \in U_1 \times U_2 \times \ldots \times U_n \times R_{n+1} \times R_{n+2} \times \ldots \subseteq \prod_{i=1}^\infty (-1,1)$$

It's **not** the case that **all** open subsets of the product look like that, but they do form a base and that's what I'm using here.

Then note that $(0,0,0\ldots 0 (\text{up to coordinate } n), 2,2,2,2 ,\ldots)$ is in the set $U_1 \times U_2 \times \ldots \times U_n \times R_{n+1} \times R_{n+2} \times \ldots$ but *not* in $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (-1,1)$, contradicting the promised inclusion. This shows that the point $(0)_{i=1}^\infty$ is not an interior point in the product topology for the set $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (-1,1)$ so that set is not open.

As to the last question: the box topology is a nice example topology for some counterexamples (and it's used in Munkres in that way) but not at all a nice topology on the product, the product topology turns out to be more natural (e.g. by its minimality and universal mapping properties ) and better behaved (preserves compactness, connectedness). Focus on the latter. The point-wise convergence topology in analysis is just the product topology in disguise (as is the weak$^*$ topology in many cases) so it's a lot more relevant..

Comment: Can we say that if the sequence of functions converges in the box topology then this sequence converges uniformly?

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev  no, not quite. There also is a uniform metric topology on the real sequences which is weaker.

Comment: thanks! Is there any topology book with emphasize to harmonic analysis (for harmonic analisist)? I read Munkres.